# Delete an entry from assigns

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

After I set the key `:current_user` in `Plug.Conn.assigns` like this:

```
conn |> assign(:current_user, user)
```

How do I drop this entry?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way:

```
Map.drop(conn.assigns, [:current_user])
```

Note that `Map.drop` takes as a second parameter `list` of keys to drop.

To apply it on conn, use:

```
conn = update_in(conn.assigns, &Map.drop(&1, [:current_user]))
```

Comment: `:current_user` is in `conn.assigns`, not `conn`.

Comment: And now you'll have to put `assigns` back into `conn`, at which point the answer becomes pretty much identical to the one @Oleksandr posted an hour ago. :)

Comment: Yes, actually it is. I just wanted to point that `Map.drop` is most natural in this case.

Comment: I like the expressiveness of this answer more. However, as @Dogbert points out, it's incomplete without the assignment. If you add it, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Added `update_in`, this is most concise and clear for me.

Answer (score 3):

To delete one of `conn.assigns` (the next examples are equivalents):

```
conn = Map.put(conn, :assigns, Map.delete(conn.assigns, :current_user))
conn = %{conn | assigns: Map.delete(conn.assigns, :current_user)}
conn = update_in(conn.assigns, &(Map.delete(&1, :current_user)))
```